# Tell GeoPandas the number of significant figures to use when writing GeoJSON geometries

Tags: python, geopandas, accuracy, precision

I have a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) `gdf`. I write its contents to a GeoJSON:

```
gdf.to_file("example.geojson")
```

which works. However, each `geometry` is specified to 16 significant figures, which is an overkill in my case.

**How can I decrease the number of significant figures?**

---

One possible way to do this is via [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html):

```
ogr2ogr example_fewer_digits.geojson example.geojson -lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=8
```

However, this still requires creating a file `example.geojson` and only then we can transform it to `example_fewer_digits.geojson`. If it was possible to achieve the same thing via GeoPandas only, it would be great.

Comment: see [Rounding all coordinates in shapely?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188622/rounding-all-coordinates-in-shapely/188739#188739)

Comment: Also, see [Rounding coordinates to five decimals in GeoPandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/321518/29431)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with polygons, rounding coordinates is something to be handled with care, as the rounding can lead to self-intersections, parts collapsing to lines,...

The safe way to do this is to use [shapely.set_precision](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.set_precision.html#shapely.set_precision). This function will round the coordinates but will also make sure the output is a valid geometry.

```
import shapely

# Round the coordinates to 8 decimals
gdf.geometry = shapely.set_precision(gdf.geometry, grid_size=0.00000001)
```

In GeoPandas 1.0, planned to be released 31 march 2024, `set_precision` will also be available like this:

```
# Round the coordinates to 8 decimals
gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.set_precision(grid_size=0.00000001)
```

Once the geometries are properly rounded, you can safely write them in that precision by specifying is to GDAL via pyogrio, as you wrote already in your answer:

```
gdf.to_file("example.geojson",engine='pyogrio',layer_options={"COORDINATE_PRECISION": 8})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pyogrio` engine & the `layer_options` kwarg of [`to_file`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file.html):

```
gdf.to_file("example.geojson",engine='pyogrio',layer_options={"COORDINATE_PRECISION": 8})
```