# Feature class to graph with networkx gives random precision of coordinates

Tags: coordinates, networkx

The coordinates from a line feature class are stored in a networkx multigraph differently. Some coordinates have 9 decimal places, others 10 decimal places. It seems to be random. I need a stable number of decimal places so that I can use the coordinates from a given list of stations as input parameters for the `nx.shortest_path` function.

```
# Create geopandas dataframe from geodatabase feature class
railroad= gdp.read_file(path_to_gdb, layer = 'railroad')

# Multipart to singlepart linestring
railroad = railroad.explode()

# Create network
G = momepy.gdf_to_nx(railroad, approach="primal")

print (G.nodes)
```

The coordinates of the nodes look like  this

```
NodeView(((2682601.1939999983, 1248221.1190000102), (2683267.109000005, 1247948.7130000032), (2683347.7720000036, 1247916.077999998), (2682777.5089999996, 1250770.3490000032)...
```

Is there a way to control the precision of coordinates with networkx? Or even a better way to access the nodes than with the coordinates?

Comment: I found the solution by using Shawn's function for rounding coordinates, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321518/rounding-coordinates-to-five-decimals-in-geopandas